# How to reuse LSTM layer and variables in variable scope (attention mechanism)

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, scope, lstm, attention-model

I have an issue in my code where I would like to share weights in my `lstm_decoder` (so essentially just use one LSTM). I know there are a few resources online on that but I am still unable to understand why the following does not share weights:

```py
initial_input = tf.unstack(tf.zeros(shape=(1,1,hidden_size2)))

for index in range(window_size):
    with tf.variable_scope('lstm_cell_decoder', reuse = index > 0):
        rnn_decoder_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size, state_is_tuple = True)

        output_decoder, state_decoder = tf.nn.static_rnn(rnn_decoder_cell, initial_input, initial_state=last_encoder_state, dtype=tf.float32)

        # Compute the score for source output vector
        scores = tf.matmul(concat_lstm_outputs, tf.reshape(output_decoder[-1],(hidden_size,1)))
        attention_coef = tf.nn.softmax(scores)
        context_vector = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(concat_lstm_outputs, tf.reshape(attention_coef, (window_size, 1))),0)
        context_vector = tf.reshape(context_vector, (1,hidden_size))

        # compute the tilda hidden state \tilde{h}_t=tanh(W[c_t, h_t]+b_t)
        concat_context = tf.concat([context_vector, output_decoder[-1]], axis = 1)
        W_tilde = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape = [hidden_size*2, hidden_size2], stddev = 0.1), name = "weights_tilde", trainable = True)
        b_tilde = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, hidden_size2]), name="bias_tilde", trainable = True)
        hidden_tilde = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(concat_context, W_tilde)+b_tilde) # hidden_tilde is [1*64]

        # update for next time step
        initial_input = tf.unstack(tf.reshape(hidden_tilde, (1,1,hidden_size2)))
        last_encoder_state = state_decoder
        print(initial_input, last_encoder_state)

        # predict the target
        W_target = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal(shape = [hidden_size2, 1], stddev = 0.1), name = "weights_target", trainable = True)
        print(W_target)
        logit = tf.matmul(hidden_tilde, W_target)
        logits = tf.concat([logits, logit], axis = 0)

logits = logits[1:]
```

I would like to use the same LSTM cell and the same W_target for each loop iteration. However, I get the following output for `print(initial_input, last_encoder_state)` and `print(W_target)` for window_size = 2 in the loop.

```py
[<tf.Tensor 'lstm_cell_decoder/unstack:0' shape=(1, 64) dtype=float32>] 
LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 
'lstm_cell_decoder/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/add_1:0' shape=(1, 64) 
dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 
'lstm_cell_decoder/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/mul_2:0' shape=(1, 64) 
dtype=float32>)
<tf.Variable 'lstm_cell_decoder/weights_target:0' shape=(64, 1) 
dtype=float32_ref>
[<tf.Tensor 'lstm_cell_decoder_1/unstack:0' shape=(1, 64) dtype=float32>] 
LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 
'lstm_cell_decoder_1/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/add_1:0' shape=(1, 64) 
dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 
'lstm_cell_decoder_1/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/mul_2:0' shape=(1, 64) 
dtype=float32>)
<tf.Variable 'lstm_cell_decoder_1/weights_target:0' shape=(64, 1) 
dtype=float32_ref>
```

Update: After Maxim's comments, I tried the following syntax

```py
for index in range(window_size):
  with tf.variable_scope('lstm_cell_decoder', reuse = index > 0):
     rnn_decoder_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size,reuse=index > 0)
     output_decoder, state_decoder = tf.nn.static_rnn(rnn_decoder_cell, ...)
     W_target = tf.get_variable(...)
```

It now shares the Variable W_target properly but there is still an issue for sharing the lstm cell/weights:

```py
<tf.Tensor 'lstm_cell_decoder/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/mul_2:0' shape=(1, 
 64) dtype=float32>]
 LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 
 'lstm_cell_decoder/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/add_1:0' shape=(1, 64) 
 dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 
'lstm_cell_decoder/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/mul_2:0' shape=(1, 64) 
 dtype=float32>)
 <tf.Variable 'lstm_cell_decoder/weights_target:0' shape=(64, 1) 
 dtype=float32_ref>

 [<tf.Tensor 'lstm_cell_decoder_1/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/mul_2:0' 
 shape=(1, 64) dtype=float32>]
 LSTMStateTuple(c=<tf.Tensor 
 'lstm_cell_decoder_1/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/add_1:0' shape=(1, 64) 
 dtype=float32>, h=<tf.Tensor 
 'lstm_cell_decoder_1/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/lstm_cell/mul_2:0' shape=(1, 64) 
 dtype=float32>)
 <tf.Variable 'lstm_cell_decoder/weights_target:0' shape=(64, 1) 
 dtype=float32_ref>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, creating variables with `tf.Variable` won't make it reusable. That's one of the key differences between [`tf.Variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable) and [`tf.get_variable`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/get_variable). See this example:

```py
with tf.variable_scope('foo', reuse=tf.AUTO_REUSE):
  for i in range(3):
    x = tf.Variable(0.0, name='x')
    y = tf.get_variable(name='y', shape=())
```

If you inspect the created variables, you'll see:

```py
<tf.Variable 'foo/x:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'foo/y:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'foo/x_1:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'foo/x_2:0' shape=() dtype=float32_ref>
```

---

Next, RNN cells provide own mechanism for the reuse. E.g., for [`tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/rnn/LSTMCell#__init__) it's `reuse` constructor argument:

```py
reuse = tf.AUTO_REUSE  # Try also True and False
cell1 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(3, reuse=reuse)
cell2 = tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(3, reuse=reuse)
outputs1, states1 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell1, X, dtype=tf.float32)
outputs2, states2 = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell2, X, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Maxim for your answer! I have an additional couple of questions: 1) in my version, tf.AUTO_REUSE does not exist, is it simply the same as setting reuse=FALSE when say my variable is first defined and then to TRUE? So something like this `for i in range(3):
    with tf.variable_scope('foo', reuse= i >0):
        x = tf.Variable(0.0, name='x')
        y = tf.get_variable(name='y', shape=())
        print(x)
        print(y)`

Comment: Yes, it's the same, but more convenient. Upgrade to TF 1.5 (or maybe even 1.4.1), `tf.AUTO_REUSE` will be available.

Comment: Please don't post the code into comments. Edit and update the question instead

Comment: Sure, I was thinking the formatting was pretty awful. I'll update the question shortly, thanks again :)

Comment: Just edited the question, the printed output is for a window_size = 2 in the loop as before.

Comment: Hm, it shows that not the variable, but the scope itself is duplicated. I think you should try `tf.AUTO_REUSE`, because you'll guarantee to have one variable scope and it'll resolve this

Comment: Right, I'll try with tf.AUTO_REUSE then. With a duplicated scope, it would mean that even though the name of the variable (lstm_cell?) is the same, the weights are still not shared?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea of scopes: you can have the same name in two scopes and that'll be different variables

Comment: After updating to 1.4.0 and using tf.AUTO_REUSE (on both the scope and the rnn cell), I get `lstm_cell_decoder/rnn/rnn/lstm_cell/mul_2:0` for the first iteration of loop and `lstm_cell_decoder/rnn_1/rnn/lstm_cell/mul_2:0` for the second..

Comment: I've just answered your another question - https://stackoverflow.com/q/48653507/712995. I think you shouldn't use the loop at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "can't reproduce that"? As in you have the same name for the variable?